# Pintest iOS SDK - 401 Authorization error on login

Tags: ios, api, pinterest

I have been able to authenticate with the Pinterest API on both the javascript and Android SDK. On iOS, I've triple-checked all of my settings to make sure I've configured everything according to the documentation.

However, when I log in through iOS, I am taken to the Pinterest app to authorize and all looks good. However, when Pinterest passes me back to my app, I am getting the following login error:

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: unauthorized (401)" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x17403dea0> { URL: https://api.pinterest.com/v1/oauth/inspect?access_token=AYalMni-yTq5Y0UihwETrFxZpzL5FK2tXvfmkbhDyJ_OP8BGeQAAAAA&token=AYalMni-yTq5Y0UihwETrFxZpzL5FK2tXvfmkbhDyJ_OP8BGeQAAAAA } { status code: 401, headers {
    Age = 0;
    "Cache-Control" = private;
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 177;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Mon, 20 Mar 2017 19:21:15 GMT";
    "Pinterest-Generated-By" = "devplatform-devapi-prod-0a01239b";
    "Pinterest-Version" = 918ef75;
    "X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
    "X-Pinterest-RID" = 280542321780;
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.pinterest.com/v1/oauth/inspect?access_token=AYalMni-yTq5Y0UihwETrFxZpzL5FK2tXvfmkbhDyJ_OP8BGeQAAAAA&token=AYalMni-yTq5Y0UihwETrFxZpzL5FK2tXvfmkbhDyJ_OP8BGeQAAAAA, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<7b227374 61747573 223a2022 6661696c 75726522 2c202263 6f646522 3a20332c 2022686f 7374223a 20226465 76706c61 74666f72 6d2d6465 76617069 2d70726f 642d3061 30313233 3962222c 20226765 6e657261 7465645f 6174223a 20224d6f 6e2c2032 30204d61 72203230 31372031 393a3231 3a313520 2b303030 30222c20 226d6573 73616765 223a2022 41757468 6f72697a 6174696f 6e206661 696c6564 2e222c20 22646174 61223a20 6e756c6c 7d>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unauthorized (401)}
```

I tried taking the access token referred to in the error response and using the token debugger on the Pinterest developer site to check it, but when I did so I got the message "An error occurred. Please try again."

So, I'm stumped. It seems to me that the access token that's being generated on iOS login is being seen as invalid by Pinterest, but I don't know how to fix that.

Do you have any thoughts on what can be done to resolve this?

Comment: Same error here... Any solution?